# LUbuntu 22.04 WiFi Hotspot - unable to connect with WPA2 (AES) security

Tags: lubuntu, security, hot-spot, wpa2

I've set up a Wifi Hotspot from LAN based on this tutorial: [Creating a hotspot in Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129579/creating-a-hotspot-in-lubuntu)

However when I choose Advanced Network Configuration / WiFi Security / WPA & WPA Personal I'm unable to connect via iPhone. (mode Hotspot, Band automatic, channel default, my device has got only B/G 2,4 GHz Wifi)

When I remove Security at all a connection is possible.

When I modify the connection

```
->nmcli connection down Hotspot

->nmcli connection modify Hotspot wifi-sec.pmf disable

->nmcli connection up Hotspot
```

(see also [Unable to connect with the hotspot created on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424633/unable-to-connect-with-the-hotspot-created-on-ubuntu))

then I can connect via WPA/WPA2 (TKIP) according to iPhone.

The previously installed Windows 10 Home could manage a Wifi Hotspot with WPA2 (AES) security, so the HW is capable of this mode.

sure, I even was able to reproduce the issue on a different Ubuntu 2022.04.

Steps processed:

1. wired connection via Advanced Network Configuration GUI -device eXYZ -left everything else as default
2. sudo apt-get install hostapd sudo apt-get install dnsmasq (because
   it was suggested here
   [Creating a hotspot in Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129579/creating-a-hotspot-in-lubuntu))

3.Create Hotspot via Advanced Network Configuration GUI:

-new WiFi -enter ssid -enter connection name mode: Hotspot

-enter device wXYZ -left everything else as defaulted

WIFI Security:

-wpa & WPA Personal

-Password

-IP4 Settings: shared to other computers was pre-selected

-save -nmcli connection up Hotspot

(connect via iPhone was not possible)

-rebot: found some dnsmasq related errors:

-sudo apt-get remove hostapd

-sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq

-reboot -nmcli connection up Hotspot

(connect via iPhone was not possible)

-nmcli connection down Hotspot

Editing Hotspot via GUI:

WiFi Security: none

-nmcli connection up Hotspot

(connect via iPhone was successful)

WIFI Security via GUI:

-wpa & WPA Personal

-Password

-nmcli connection down

Hotspot -nmcli connection modify Hotspot wifi-sec.pmf disable

-nmcli connection up Hotspot

(as suggested here [Unable to connect with the hotspot created on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424633/unable-to-connect-with-the-hotspot-created-on-ubuntu))

(connection via iPhone was possible, warning weak security)

Message on iPhone: WPA/WPA2 (TKIP) is not considered secure. If this is your Wifi network, confgure the router to use WPA2 (AES) or WPA3

How do I change my setup to be able to connect via WPA2 (AES) security?

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem.

Comment: sure, I even was able to reproduce the issue on a different Ubuntu 2022.04.
See my edits above. What can I do to change my Hotspot's security to WPA2 (AES) and establish a successful connection via iPhone?

Comment: How can I find out if maybe the used out-of-the-box wifi driver is not capable of WPA2 AES?